# C++ Class Representing Network Packet

Tags: c++, embedded

I program mainly in C for the embedded world and recently I have been experimenting around with C++ and I have an idea. This question pertains to data transferred over a network.
Currently in C I do something like this contrived example (disregarding packing):

```
typedef struct {
    time_t date;
    float value;
} Message1;       

typedef union {
    char raw[sizeof(Message1)];
    Message1 msg;
} Overlay;

int my_func(Message1* ptr)
{
    /* do stuff with stuff */
}
```

Data is placed into `Overlay.raw` and inspected through `msg` (regarding endianness of course). Can I do something similar in C++ without using a struct?

```
class Message1 {
    public:
        time_t date;
        float value;
        int my_func() { /* do stuff with stuff */ };
}

typedef union {
    char raw[sizeof(Message1)];
    Message1 msg;
}
```

I've done some experiments and from what I can tell it *seems* to be working so far. However I want to know more details about how C++ aligns stuff in the class. Like, will it break if I put a `private` section after the `public` section? What if I use inheritance? Is this a Dumb(tm) thing to do?

Comment: Yuck.  Please don't do this.  Just make member functions that accept/return a pointer to the serialized message.  Encapsulation is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You generally want to keep unions simple.  None of the construct, copy, assign, or move semantics apply to them; even if members have the functions defined.  It's generally not a good idea to use them with complex data types though, since you need to worry about vtables, placement of access modified members, etc...  *However*, POD classes are basically the same as C structs (C++ structs are also essentially the same as classes).

As I understand it, memory layout isn't part of C++ the standard, aside from the order of member variables for POD types.  Public, protected, and private variables can be placed in separate memory regions.  I think inherited member layouts are also implementation defined.  So any code that would depend on layout would be platform/compiler specific.  Members are generally laid out in sequential order, but again it's generally not a good idea to depend on layout (multiple inheritance for example).  Obviously alignments are still platform/compiler defined as well, but you can control alignment using `alignas(T)` (C++11).

Also, it's probably just style preference, but it might be better to use the union as an explicit type. instead of a typedef.

```
union pkt {
    char raw[sizeof(Message)]
    Message msg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a good reason to use unions here, at all.
You get no benefit of using a union with a byte array over a cast of the struct pointer to a (char*).

If you want to send a packet you don't need a union to access the data.

```
typedef struct {
    time_t date;
    float value;
} Message1;   

void sendData(uin8_t *pData, int size)
{
  while (size--)
     sendByte(*pData++);
}

int main()
{
  Message1 myMessage;
  sendData( &myMessage, sizeof(myMessage) );
}
```

Btw. Sending data directly from a structure over a network results regular in problems with padding and/or endianess between different platforms.

Comment: The union is used so that I can type-pun my message struct onto a char array. I recognize that I can just use a uint8_t pointer to transmit (with respect to endianness of course) but the union is very useful for receiving packets.